# Very low accuracy (0.11) and it remains constant after few epochs on MNIST database

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, python, backpropagation, accuracy

I am developing my ANN *from scratch* which is supposed to classify [MNIST database](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) of handwritten digits (0-9). My feed-forward fully connected ANN *has to be* composed of:

1. One input layer, with `28x28 = 784` nodes (that is, features of each image)
2. One hidden layer, with `1,2,3,4` or `5` nodes (shallow network)
3. One output layer, with `10` nodes (one for each predicted class)

and *has to* compute gradient w.r.t. weights and bias thanks to backpropagation algorithm and, finally, it should learn exploiting gradient descent with momentum algorithm.

The loss function is: `cross-entropy + softmax`, since the task is about *classification*.

Each hidden neuron is activated by the same activation function, the `sigmoid`; meanwhile the output's neurons are activated by the `identity` function.

The dataset has been divided into:

1. `60.000` training pairs `(image, label)` - for the training
2. `5000` validation pairs `(image, label)` - for evaluation and select the network which minimize the validation loss
3. `5000` testing pairs `(image, label)` - for testing the model picked using new metrics such as accuracy

This is the curves I get about training and validation loss: [image: training-validation loss] and these are some logs about their loss and accuracy on the validation set:

```
E(0) on TrS is: -0.09995663952048875  on VS is: -0.10000215508367913  Accuracy: 9.120000000000001 %
E(1) on TrS is: -0.09997782058505714  on VS is: -0.10000721545529842  Accuracy: 9.120000000000001 %
...
E(47) on TrS is: -0.1000167196491167  on VS is: -0.10001587893489938  Accuracy: 11.42 %
E(48) on TrS is: -0.10001676221437443  on VS is: -0.10001594086326895  Accuracy: 11.42 %
E(49) on TrS is: -0.10001680503178402  on VS is: -0.10001599995199295  Accuracy: 11.42 %

Validation loss is minimum at epoch: 22
```

Finally, if I test the network at epoch `22`, which is the epoch where the validation loss is minimum, I get the following result:

```
Accuracy score on test set is: 11.28 %
```

These are my questions: as you can see, the accuracy remains (almost) constant and it is *very* low. It has a low value on the test set as well and on the training set. Is that normal? If it is *not*, how can I fix?

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import xlog1py
from scipy.special import expit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mnist.loader import MNIST


def softmax(y):
    e_y = np.exp(y - np.max(y))
    return e_y / e_y.sum()

def cross_entropy(y, t, derivative=False, post_process=True):
    if post_process:
        if derivative:
            return y - t
        return -np.sum(np.sum(xlog1py(t, softmax(y)), axis=0))

def sigmoid(a, derivative=False):
    f_a = expit(-a)
    if derivative:
        return np.multiply(f_a, (1 - f_a))
    return f_a

def identity(a, derivative=False):
    f_a = a
    if derivative:
        return np.ones(np.shape(a))
    return f_a

def accuracy_score(targets, predictions):
    correct_predictions = 0
    for item in range(np.shape(predictions)[1]):
        # print(predictions[:, item])  # dbg
        argmax_idx = np.argmax(predictions[:, item])
        # print("argmax idx", argmax_idx)  # dbg
        # print(targets_test[:, item])  # dbg
        if targets[argmax_idx, item] == 1:
            correct_predictions += 1
    return correct_predictions / np.shape(predictions)[1]


def one_hot(targets):
    return np.asmatrix(np.eye(np.max(targets) + 1)[targets]).T


def plot(epochs, loss_train, loss_val):
    plt.plot(epochs, loss_train)
    plt.plot(epochs, loss_val, color="orange")
    plt.legend(["Training Loss", "Validation Loss"])
    plt.xlabel("Epochs")
    plt.ylabel("Loss")
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self):
        self.layers = []

    def add_layer(self, layer):
        self.layers.append(layer)

    def build(self):
        for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers):
            if i == 0:
                layer.type = "input"
            else:
                layer.type = "output" if i == len(self.layers) - 1 else "hidden"
                layer.configure(self.layers[i - 1].neurons)

    def fit(self, X_train, targets_train, X_val, targets_val, max_epochs=50):
        e_loss_train = []
        e_loss_val = []

        # Getting the minimum loss on validation set
        predictions_val = self.predict(X_val)
        min_loss_val = cross_entropy(predictions_val, targets_val)

        best_net = self  # net which minimize validation loss
        best_epoch = 0  # epoch where the validation loss is minimum

        # batch mode
        for epoch in range(max_epochs):
            predictions_train = self.predict(X_train)
            self.back_prop(targets_train, cross_entropy)
            self.learning_rule(l_rate=0.000001, momentum=0.9)
            loss_train = cross_entropy(predictions_train, targets_train)
            e_loss_train.append(loss_train)

            # Validation
            predictions_val = self.predict(X_val)
            loss_val = cross_entropy(predictions_val, targets_val)
            e_loss_val.append(loss_val)

            print("E(%d) on TrS is:" % epoch, loss_train, " on VS is:", loss_val, " Accuracy:",
                  accuracy_score(targets_val, predictions_val) * 100, "%")

            if loss_val < min_loss_val:
                min_loss_val = loss_val
                best_epoch = epoch
                best_net = self

        print("Validation loss is minimum at epoch:", best_epoch)

        plot(np.arange(max_epochs), e_loss_train, e_loss_val)

        return best_net

    # Matrix of predictions where the i-th column corresponds to the i-th item
    def predict(self, dataset):
        z = dataset.T
        for layer in self.layers:
            z = layer.forward_prop_step(z)
        return z

    def back_prop(self, target, loss):
        for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers[:0:-1]):
            next_layer = self.layers[-i]
            prev_layer = self.layers[-i - 2]
            layer.back_prop_step(next_layer, prev_layer, target, loss)

    def learning_rule(self, l_rate, momentum):
        # Momentum GD
        for layer in [layer for layer in self.layers if layer.type != "input"]:
            layer.update_weights(l_rate, momentum)
            layer.update_bias(l_rate, momentum)


class Layer:

    def __init__(self, neurons, type=None, activation=None):
        self.dE_dW = None  # derivatives dE/dW where W is the weights matrix
        self.dE_db = None  # derivatives dE/db where b is the bias
        self.dact_a = None  # derivative of the activation function
        self.out = None  # layer output
        self.weights = None  # input weights
        self.bias = None  # layer bias
        self.w_sum = None  # weighted_sum
        self.neurons = neurons  # number of neurons
        self.type = type  # input, hidden or output
        self.activation = activation  # activation function
        self.deltas = None  # for back-prop

    def configure(self, prev_layer_neurons):
        self.set_activation()
        self.weights = np.asmatrix(np.random.normal(-0.1, 0.02, (self.neurons, prev_layer_neurons)))
        self.bias = np.asmatrix(np.random.normal(-0.1, 0.02, self.neurons)).T  # vettore colonna


    def set_activation(self):
        if self.activation is None:
            if self.type == "hidden":
                self.activation = sigmoid
            elif self.type == "output":
                self.activation = identity

    def forward_prop_step(self, z):
        if self.type == "input":
            self.out = z
        else:
            self.w_sum = np.dot(self.weights, z) + self.bias
            self.out = self.activation(self.w_sum)
        return self.out

    def back_prop_step(self, next_layer, prev_layer, target, local_loss):
        if self.type == "output":
            self.dact_a = self.activation(self.w_sum, derivative=True)
            self.deltas = np.multiply(self.dact_a,
                                      local_loss(self.out, target, derivative=True))
        else:
            self.dact_a = self.activation(self.w_sum, derivative=True)  # (m,batch_size)
            self.deltas = np.multiply(self.dact_a, np.dot(next_layer.weights.T, next_layer.deltas))

        self.dE_dW = self.deltas * prev_layer.out.T

        self.dE_db = np.sum(self.deltas, axis=1)

    def update_weights(self, l_rate, momentum):
        # Momentum GD
        self.weights = self.weights - l_rate * self.dE_dW
        self.weights = -l_rate * self.dE_dW + momentum * self.weights

    def update_bias(self, l_rate, momentum):
        # Momentum GD
        self.bias = self.bias - l_rate * self.dE_db
        self.bias = -l_rate * self.dE_db + momentum * self.bias


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mndata = MNIST(path="data", return_type="numpy", mode="randomly_binarized")
    X_train, targets_train = mndata.load_training()  # 60.000 images, 28*28 features
    X_val, targets_val = mndata.load_testing()  # 10.000 images, 28*28 features

    # Getting the test set splitting the validation set in two equal parts
    # Validation set size decreases from 10.000 to 5000 (of course)
    X_val, X_test = np.split(X_val, 2)  # 5000 images, 28*28 features
    targets_val, targets_test = np.split(targets_val, 2)

    targets_train = one_hot(targets_train)
    targets_val = one_hot(targets_val)
    targets_test = one_hot(targets_test)

    net = NeuralNetwork()
    d = np.shape(X_train)[1]  # number of features, 28*28
    c = np.shape(targets_train)[0]  # number of classes, 10

    # Shallow network with 1 hidden neuron
    # That is 784, 1, 10
    for m in (d, 1, c):
        layer = Layer(m)
        net.add_layer(layer)

    net.build()

    best_net = net.fit(X_train, targets_train, X_val, targets_val, max_epochs=50)

    predictions = best_net.predict(X_test)
    print("Accuracy score on test set is:", accuracy_score(targets_test, predictions) * 100, "%")
```

Note that:

1. The performance are similar even though I set `5` hidden neurons
   instead of `1`
2. Accuracy on training set is very low as well (around `11 %`)

Comment: 5 nodes is basically nothing, have you tried with 500? If the accuracy remain the same then I would start worrying about the code implementation.

Comment: @EdoardoGuerriero accuracy is low

Comment: @EdoardoGuerriero I would disagree with the fact that the number of nodes is not enough. According to the [original mnist paper](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-98.pdf) a naiive linear classifier got an *error rate* of roughly 12%. Note that error rate is different than accuracy. Also if accuracy is 11%, then that means it's basically picking a number at random.

Comment: Any solution? @juicedatom